# refresh page without refreshing the iframe

Tags: java, html, jsp

I have a `jsp` file in which I am showing external page at the top of the page (using iframe) & other part is the output of html code written in the `jsp` file.

**HTML Code looks like:**

```
<body>
    <iframe src="http://www.example.com"
            width="100%" 
            height="60" 
            style="border: none;"
            id="ifrm">
    </iframe>
    <table>.....</table>
    <table>.....</table>
</body>
```

Now I want to refresh page programmatically without refreshing the `iframe`.

My question is that Can I refresh page without refreshing the `iframe`?

Answers/hints will be appreciated.

Comment: Yes. Use AJAX to refresh content (in your case other than iframe) without refreshing whole page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `iframe` is embedded in the the main HMTL page (or the the JSP). So if page is refreshed, the iframe is going to be loaded again for sure.

To avoid that, I can think of following two options:

1. Use AJAX to populate the remaining content of the page. This will involve making Ajax Call and rendering the contents (`<table>..</table>` etc.)again.
2. Easier option: put the remaining content in another iframe. This will involve creating another JSP page for the remaining content.